# Dumping mongodb error: error dialing cluster0-shard-00-00.fklgt.mongodb.net:27017: SSL errors: SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate

Tags: mongodb, ssl, mongoose, mongodb-atlas, mongodump

I usually dump my mongodb database using this command and it works perfectly:

```
mongodump --uri mongodb+srv://name:password@cluster0.fklgt.mongodb.net/database_name --archive="dump-copy-name" --forceTableScan
```

However, I have been trying to dump different databases and it just keeps logging this:

> 2021-06-21T18:43:39.206+0100    error dialing
> cluster0-shard-00-00.fklgt.mongodb.net:27017: SSL errors: SSL
> routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed

Any idea what's going-on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mongodump tool does not implicitly trust your system certificate store.  You will need to pass it the root CA certificate so that it can validate the cluster's certificate.

To find out which certificate is the root, use openssl:

```
openssl s_client -connect cluster0-shard-00-00.fklgt.mongodb.net:27017
```

The output should include a `certificate chain` section like:

```
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=New York/L=New York/O=MongoDB, Inc./CN=*.mongodb.com
   i:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/CN=DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA
 1 s:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/CN=DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA
   i:/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=DigiCert Global Root CA
---
```

(this is an example, test with your cluster to get the real certificates)

The highest numbered certificate in the chain should be the root.  Once you have that, google for the `CN` part (in my example that was "DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA"), and you should find a link to download the certificate.

The root should be one of the two listed here: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/faq/security/#hard-coded-certificate-authority

Once you have the root certificate in .pem format, use the command line option `--sslCAFile=<filename>` to pass it to mongodump.

Comment: Thanks. But, how come the command used to work perfectly fine a few days ago without doing any of this?

Comment: And when you say "(this is an example, test with your cluster to get the real certificates)". Which part should I change exactly?

Comment: I couldn't even connect to the database with the mongo shell because of the same problem which I find strange because everything used to work perfectly fine.

Comment: MongoDB Atlas changed their certificate provider recently, so it may be that your cluster just got a new cert signed by the new root.  That output is from the mongodb.com website, run the openssl command noted to get the response from your cluster.